# How to set up UIAlert to display a lot of information?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I want to set up a UIAlert as a "check" for a user. The user will be going to save a set of information, but I would like to give the user a chance to review the information after hitting the "save" button. Essentially, they hit "save", and then I want a UIAlert to appear showing the information they are saving asking "Are you sure all of this information is correct:" and then display all of the info :

```
@IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //create alert (I know how to do this) that shows all info (I don't know how to do this)
        //If user is ok with the info, perform a segue, if not return to page
}
```

The issue is that I know `UIAlerts` can have components like "title" and "message" but I would like the alert to display a lot of information in a list like fashion. Is there anyway to do this? Or do I need to not use an alert and, instead, maybe bring it to a different, confirmation page or maybe a different UI element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show an alert on a view controller, the following code can be used.

```
let a = UIAlertController(title: "Your title", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
a.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
    // Pressed "OK"
}))
self.present(a, animated: true, completion: { finished in
    // Alert shown
})
```

However there is a limit to how much information can be fit inside an alert. If you have something longer, creating a new view controller and modally presenting it could also work. This would let you customize how you wanted information to be presented (e.g. with a scroll / page view). You can also customize your view controller to make it look like an alert, so that the purpose of it is clearer. To present a view controller modally, you can use the `present` method.

```
self.present(otherViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

One method I have used in the path to make an alert-like modal view controller is presenting a smaller view controller over the current one, and changing it's modal presentation style so that you can see the base view controller through it.

```
let otherVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OtherViewController") as! OtherViewController
otherVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
otherVC.view.center = vc.view.center
otherVC.delegate = self //Create a delegate so that you can control actions such as "OK" buttons
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //Stop the user interacting with the view controller behind the alert
self.present(otherVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edit:
You can make the delegate control actions such as closing the alert with actions. For example, this could be an example of your delegate:

```
protocol AlertDelegate {
    func didCancel()
    func didOkay()
}
```

Then, you could implement this like so:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController, AlertDelegate {
    func didCancel() { ... }
    func didOkay() { ... }

    func showAlert() {
        ...
        otherVC.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in your Alert View Controller, you can interact with the delegate.

```
class MyAlert: UIViewController {
    var delegate: AlertDelegate!

    @IBAction func cancelButton(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.didCancel()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

So, when the cancel button is clicked on the alert view controller, the delegate would say it cancelled, and the modal view controller would be dismissed. Then, the root view controller would receive this action, and could handle it accordingly.

Comment: I like this idea. How do I then eventually close the overtop viewController (otherVC)? And, with this set up, can I run code from the original VC, lets say after the user hits "Ok" in otherVC and otherVC closes?...
Like I want the saveButton on the originalVC to open the otherVC displaying the info... the user hits "Ok" in otherVC, the otherVC closes/disappears, and then I want the rest of the `saveButtonTapped` code to run from the original VC?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki Yeah, the delegate comes in handy here. See the edit I did for more info.

Comment: I have one more question. You called `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` in the RootViewController when the button was hit. Obviously, I need to set `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in the otherVC once either button has run ("ok" or "cancel"), but how do I refer to that RootViewController in the otherVC's code? I tried:
`let rootVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootViewController") as! RootViewController` and then, in the "ok" button in the otherVC, `rootVC.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` but this did not work.

Comment: @AlekPiasecki you would put this in your delegate functions, which is called when either button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use the `UIAlertViewController` to present a lot of lines and it will handle scroll automatically. But the question is, if is usable and pretty enough?

Have a look at this simple example:

```
    @IBAction func showAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {        
        var lines = [String]()
        for i in 1...100 {
            lines.append("this is line \(i)")
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: lines.joined(separator: "\n"), preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Which gives me this view:

[image: alert view with many lines]

with scrollable content.

A few problems and considerations:

1. There seems to be an upper limit. If I change this to `for i in 1...500` for instance I don't see any content
2. This is not really that user friendly I think

So...I think you should consider another solution than `UIAlertViewController` :)

Hope that helps you.

Comment: There's an iOS design guideline recommending that you don't add so much info that a `UIAlertViewController` has to scroll also.

Comment: @DanielStorm ah...thanks, that makes perfect sense. The content kind of clutters the `UIAlertViewController` doesn't it